# Another query in pre_get_post cause memory issue

Tags: pre-get-posts

I am trying to modify the main query on a taxonomy term page by using `pre_get_posts` action and `post__in` field. To add IDs to post__in field I have to run a query. When I call this query I run into a "Fatal error: Allowed memory size..." issue. If I call the same query in a template file that works great. I think I should use some different method to achieve my goal. How could I run a query inside `pre_get_posts`?
I would like to only modify main query instead of replace with a custom query, or create a custom page.

```
function custom_loops($query) {
if (is_tax( 'service_photo_location' )){
    $ids = get_nearby_partners_by_area(50000, 'service_photo');
    $query->set( 'post__in', $ids);
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10);
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'custom_meta_partner_subscription_level');
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value title');
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC');
}
remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_loops' );
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_loops');

function get_nearby_partners_by_area($distance, $post_type){
    $post_ids = array();
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post_type'=> 'wedding_dress', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'fields' => 'ids' );
    $all_partners = get_posts( $args ); //at tis point i get memory error
    foreach ( $all_partners as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
        // this point I calculate some things
        $post_ids = $post->ID;
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $post_ids;
}
```

Comment: I spy infinite recursion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the action before you run the internal query, and always verify main query with `is_main_query`:

```
function custom_loops($query) {
    if ( $query->is_tax( 'service_photo_location' ) && $query->is_main_query() ){
        remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_loops' );
        $ids = get_nearby_partners_by_area(50000, 'service_photo');
        // ...
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_loops');
```

Comment: Ohh. `$query->is_main_query()` solved my issue. Thank you.